# veraltet vs veraltend

Tags: word-choice

I'm marking some definitions as 'archaic' and some as 'obsolete'. From what I understand, `veralten` means for something to become outdated.

So I think the definitions could be marked up as:

- `veraltet` - obsolete / no longer in use (past participle)
- `veraltend` - archaic / becoming obsolete (present participle)

Is this correct? Can the words ever be used interchangeably? Are any other words preferred when trying to say that a definition is archaic or obsolete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Grammar viewpont *veraltet* and *veraltend* are, respectively, the *Partizip II* and *Partizip I* of the verb *veralten*, which means become obsolete. The *Partizip I* is formed as follows:

> `Infinitiv`+`d` [+`Adjektiv Endung`, if needed]

You are right. The in the form of *Partizip II* the verb means that it *is already* obsolete, out-dated, while the  *Partizip I* means, in the process of becoming obsolete, z.B.

> - schnell veraltende Methoden (methods rapidly becoming obsolete)
> - veraltete Methoden (the obsolete methods)

Answer (score 4):

Concerning your last question, a few similar words:

- *altmodisch* – *old-fashioned*
- *ungebräuchlich* – something is rarely used (no statement concerning the trend).
- *außer Gebrauch* – *out of use*.
- *außer Gebrauch geratend* – something is becoming out of use.
- *archaisch* and *antiquiert* – emphasising that something is old (older than something that is *veraltet*). Some people may still use it anyway.

The following three classify whether it still makes sense to use something but not how often something is actually used (something *überflüssig* may still be used by the majority):

- *obsolet* – something is not really required or needed anymore
- *überholt* – something that has been replaced (lit. overtaken) by a new standard.
- *überflüssig* – something that grants no benefit anymore *(superfluous).*

Answer (score -1):

*Veralten* does indeed mean **to become** obsolete (or an Unwort-candidate for growing old), *veraltet* means **to be** obsolete (or outdated),  and *veraltend* means **to make** obsolete. Since these words mean different things, you can't use them interchangeably. At that, only *veraltet* is a common word, with synonyms like *obsolet*, *archaisch*, and *altmodisch* (old-fashioned).

Comment: Disagree. As you say, _veralten_ means _to become obsolete_; thus, _veraltend_ means _becoming obsolete_, _obsolescent_, and it is absolutely common in dictionaries. An alternative would be _altertümlich_.

Comment: Be careful not to mix up verbs (*veralten*) and past participles (*veraltet*). The word *veraltet* all by itself does NOT mean *to be obsolete*. It still needs the auxiliary verb *sein*.    Considering this, it sure is correct that *veraltend sein* can describe the ability *to make something obsolete*, but I cannot recall any situation where such a term would be used in German.